# Converting PB 9 classic app to .Net winform

Tags: winforms, powerbuilder.net

I have a `powerbuilder 9` app and we are converting that to .net.  To do this, I am following the below approach :

1. Convert powerbuilder 9 app to powerbuilder classic 12.5. - Completed successfully.
2. Convert powerbuilder classic 12.5 app to powerbuilder.net 12.5 app. - In progress, with build errors.
3. Create .Net dlls in pb.net 12.5
4. Refer pb.net 12.5 dlls in .Net winforms project to reuse the existing forms and the code. - Pending.

In step 2, I am facing issues for building the app successfully.

After conversion, I got the below **errors :**

1. There is a functionality to create excel sheet.  After conversion, there is an error at the below line.

   - workbook.Sheets(1).CELLS[1,8].columnwidth=9
   - Error C0014: Undefined variable: columnwidth
2. There is an error at GOTO statement.

   - Syntax/statement in the code:  GOTO IssuerLtrsOnly1,       IssuerLtrsOnly1:
   - Error:  No label 'IssuerLtrsOnly1' within the scope of the GoTo statement.

I commented the above lines to see the successful build.  Unfortunately, below is the error i got again and with this error I am unable to find the location of the error.  On double click of the error, it is not pointing to the error location after target corecompile.

**Below is the build information:**

> PowerScript compile complete -- 0 error(s), 92 warning(s)
>   MSBuild started... output path:
>       C:\Data\DUTCH\PB 12.5\Copy of DAU_PB_CODE_dot net 12.5\wpf\auction.out\bin\Debug
>   Project "auction.csproj" (default targets):
>
> Target CoreCompile
>       Csc: Error CS1510 u_apol_nv_wizard.uf_display_step(II) (23,67): A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable
>       Csc: Error CS1510 u_apol_nv_wizard.uf_display_step(II) (27,66): A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable

Answer (score 0):

Error#2 goto is unsupported feature in PB.NET